# Revit parameters are getting renamed when a Revit file is being imported into Forge autodesk-model-derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Please find attached the issue that we are seeing in Forge. The parameters are getting renamed when a Revit file is being imported into forge. When we click on the properties of the element after uploading the file on forge, we find that some parameter names get changed. Due to this when we try exporting those parameters into a database or excel sheet we lose information. Please try to see how we can escalate this issue. We need to know if this is something to do with our systems, or files or with Forge in general. It did not used to happen earlier, but it is repeating now on all new files that are being uploaded.

Following is the link to a sample file for reference:-
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ck1hpyxpyte2tya/AABSOUqzKMjPtpfax7ULSloia/SCM-Qty-Test1.rvt?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Forge Team is investigating.  I'll update you as soon as we figure out what is going on.
Cheers